# Inherit view - add attribute maxlength to char (input text in web) field

Tags: inheritance, attributes, odoo, odoo-14

Inherit view - add attribute maxlength to char (input text in web) field
Avatar
Victor Torralba
24 mayo 2022
viewsinheritanceattributes

Hello, I'm trying to add the attribute maxlength="100" to the description field in the products form.

I've done an inheritance and also modified 'placeholder' value and added a new class 'border' to the element.

But I'n not able to define maxlength=10.

Here is the code:

```html
<odoo>
  <data>
    <record id="inherit_view_product_template_product_form" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">inherit_view_product_template_product.form</field>
      <field name="model">product.template</field>
      <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view" />
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='name']" position="attributes">
          <field name="name" placeholder="Max length 10 chars">
            <attribute name="class" add="border" remove="" separator=" " />
            <attribute name="maxlength" add="10" remove="" separator=" " />
          </field>
        </xpath>
      </field>
    </record>
  </data>
</odoo>
```

What am I missing?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you, at the end I read about constrains by Python and I solve it.
`code`     @api.constrains('name')
    def _check_description(self):
        for description in self:
            if len(description.name) > 100:
                raise ValidationError("El campo descripción debe tener 100 caracteres como máximo.")
`code`

Comment: I'm not able to format the code, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it from `xml`, What you can do is:

1. Use constraints to show error message if size more than specific number and this error will raise once you click on save button :

```
@api.constrains('name')
def _check_name(self):
    for product in self:
        if len(product.name) > 10:
            raise ValidationError('The name of product must be less than or equal 10 characters')
```

1. You can set the size attribute on field level:

```
 name = fields.Char('Name', index=True, required=True, translate=True, size=10)
```